# generic misunderstanding when tying to add to list

Tags: java, list, generics, data-structures

**this a wildcard question.**

my purpose is to make a list that contains a class that has a generic type with extended examples:

so this is the structure:

```
  public class Event<T extends ActionType>{
  }

  public abstract class ActionType{
  }

  //**many** classes that extends ActionType class
```

that's a list that hold classes that extends from **ActionType**

```
  private List<Event<ActionType>> list = ArrayList<>();

  Event<RightClick> event = new Event<>(xPosition, yPosition, delay, new RightClick(robot), clicks, robot);

  list.add(event);
```

I know that's I cant do this to make sure that I can add the extended items:

```
  private List<Event<ActionType>> list = ArrayList<>();
```

but what I can do to add the items to the same list.

**to fix** my problem I used the wildcard selector **?**

```
 List<Event<? extends ActionType>>
```

Comment: Generics are invariant. A `List<Event<ActionType>>` will not accept `Event<RightClick>`, only `Event<ActionType>`. Understand generics and adjust your generic type restrictions. If generics would be covariant, then you could give someone who expects a `List<Animal>` a `List<Dog>` and then add `Cat`s to it. Which would cause heap corruption as `dogs.get(0)` could suddenly be a `Cat`.

Comment: You should use wildcards. you could specify `List<Event<? extends ActionType>>` for example. You could also leave it since `Event` specifies this already for its type, so just `List<EventType<?>>`.

Comment: @Zabuzard but I can't tell List<Animal> cuz the Animal class is generic I am quite a beginner .

Comment: @Zabuzard  but when I use List<EventType<?>> I specify the type to only one EventType witch I want to use all the EventTypes I gonna edit it to an animal to make it easier to understand

Comment: Sounds like you misunderstand wildcards. With the wildcard this list **will** accept events of rightclicks, events of leftclicks, events of whatever. It solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

Generics are **invariant**. A `List<Event<ActionType>>` will not accept `Event<RightClick>`, only `Event<ActionType>`.

Understand generics and adjust your generic type restrictions.

If generics **would be covariant**, then you could give someone who expects a `List<Animal>` a `List<Dog>` and then add `Cat`s to it. Which would cause **heap corruption** as `dogs.get(0)` could suddenly be a `Cat`.

An example:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
dogs.add(new Dog());

List<Animal> animals = dogs; // pretend this would work
animals.add(new Cat()); // would be legit

Dog dog = dogs.get(1); // should be safe, but is cat, heap corruption
```

A `List<Animal>` explicitly says that this list must accept **all** animals, also cats. But a `List<Dog>` is restricted to dogs only. The two lists behave differently, they have different restrictions, hence you can not use one for another. Unlike a `Dog` who is an `Animal`, a `List<Dog>` is not an `List<Animal>`, that is what is meant by co- and invariance.

---

### Solution

The correct tool to *"accept any `ActionType`, I do not care"* are **wildcards**. So either go with

```
 List<Event<? extends ActionType>>
```

or just

```
List<Event<?>>
```

since the `Event` class already specifies the `T extends ActionType` restriction.

With that type you will be able to add all sorts of `Event`s to it:

```
Event<RightClick> rightClick = ...
Event<LeftClick> leftClick = ...
Event<MiddleClick> middleClick = ...

list.add(rightClick);
list.add(leftClick);
list.add(middleClick);
```

As a consequence of the `?` wildcard you will not be able to know the actual type at compile-time anymore, so:

```
Event<?> event = list.get(0); // unknown which exact type
```

All you know of `?` is that it is at least `extends ActionType`, so you will be able to use all sorts of methods that are given by `ActionType`, but nothing introduced only in `RightClick` for example. That would require an explicit cast (guarded by an `instanceof` check), although I would question your design if you have to use right-click specific things there.